# For loops with var

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following function. I would like to loops through each var and check if it equals correct.

```
        function checkAnswers(){

            DropdownVal1 = $('#dropdown1 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal2 = $('#dropdown2 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal3 = $('#dropdown3 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal4 = $('#dropdown4 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal5 = $('#dropdown5 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal6 = $('#dropdown6 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal7 = $('#dropdown7 option:selected').val()
            DropdownVal8 = $('#dropdown8 option:selected').val()


            for (var i = 1;i<9;i++)
            {


                    if(DropdownVal+i == "correct"){
                        console.log("correct" + i)  
                    }
            }


        }
```

My console is saying it can't find DropdownVal so I'm assuming it is not concatenating properly with i

How do I concatenate a variable in a loop?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Surprised it does not allow this! Thanks

Comment: If it allowed this syntax, how could it tell if you were adding `i` to the variable name, or the value?

Comment: Also, you don't need to select the `option:selected`. Just do this: `$('#dropdown1').val()`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function checkAnswers(){

        for (var i = 1;i<9;i++)
        {

                var val = $('#dropdown'+i+' option:selected').val();
                if(val == "correct"){
                    console.log("correct" + i)  
                }
        }


    }
```

in this case you create dynamic selector and get it value on each loop iterate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use DropdownVal and a number you normally use the array datatype. Through which you can iterate by the index. More info about arrays and other datatypes could be found at http://javascript.info/tutorial/array

```
function checkAnswers(){

    var DropdownVal = [];

    DropdownVal[0] = $('#dropdown1 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[1] = $('#dropdown2 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[2] = $('#dropdown3 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[3] = $('#dropdown4 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[4] = $('#dropdown5 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[5] = $('#dropdown6 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[6] = $('#dropdown7 option:selected').val()
    DropdownVal[7] = $('#dropdown8 option:selected').val()


    for (var i = 1;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(DropdownVal[i] == "correct") {
             console.log("correct" + i);  
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Arrays:

```
    function checkAnswers(){

        var dropdowns = [ $('#dropdown1 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown2 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown3 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown4 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown5 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown6 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown7 option:selected').val(),
                          $('#dropdown8 option:selected').val() ];


        for (var i = 0;i<dropdowns.length ;i++)
        {
                if(dropdowns[i] == "correct"){
                    console.log("correct" + i)  
                }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
function checkAnswers(){

    for (var i = 1;i<9;i++)
    {
            if ( $("#dropdown"+i+" option:selected").val() == "correct"){
                console.log("correct" + i)  
            }
    }

}
```